# Can't unmount ISO

Tags: windows-10, powershell

Yesterday I mounted an ISO. Now I'm done with the files and I want to unmount and delete the folder. Upon attempting to eject the ISO, I keep getting this error:

> An error occurred while ejecting 'CD Drive (F:) ISO_NAME'

So I figured I'd give PowerShell a try.  I opened Powershell as administrator, and was able to "unmount" the ISO using `mountvol F: /d`. This "Fixed" the issue, as the ISO didn't show up in explorer as mounted.

Now I want to delete the folder that housed the ISO files, but I get another error saying the folder was in use. I restarted my computer, and lo and behold, the ISO is still mounted as if I never used PowerShell in the first place. Attempting to use PowerShell again to unmount it via the same command, (Still running in admin mode, mind) I'm getting an "access is denied" error within PowerShell.

Using `Dismount-DiskImage -ImagePath "C:\PATH"`does absolutely nothing as well. No errors, but it doesn't change anything.

Simply put, how can I remove this mounted ISO from my computer?

Comment: How did you mount it in the first place?

Comment: @DavidPostill I had thought I was going to have to download a program, but I ended up using ISO viewer that came with win 10, and I can't seem to find a space to unmount from that program.

Comment: Can you try ejecting the disk in safe mode?

Comment: @DavidPostill I actually didn't think of that...I just did that a minute ago after seeing your comment; The ISO wasn't even mounted in safe mode, and I was able to delete the folder that had them, and now that I'm out of safe mode, the ISO is finally gone. Thank you.

Comment: Added an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I want to delete the folder that housed the ISO files

> I get another error saying the folder was in use.

Boot into safe mode, unmount the ISO if it is still mounted, and then delete the files.

Comment: Overkill. You don't need to resort to safe mode for this job.

Answer (score 1):

Open up the Disk Management utility and right click the drive that the ISO is mounted on and click Eject from there (instead of from File Explorer.)

The drive wont automatically remove itself from your device list when ejecting this way, either restart or manually remove to remove it from the list.

Answer (score 0):

Press window key or the start menu and then type device manager then go to the disk drive you want to remove then it restart and the cd drive will be removed